# unix alias command to copy the files and overwrite

Tags: unix

I have written `alias` to copy the files from `/tmp` directory and overwrite the existing file. But when I run the alias i get a prompt to overwrite the files for which I need to input `yes`. Below is the alias I have written:

```
alias deploy="cd /app/my-project/ && cp -rf /tmp/dist.tar.gz
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias deploy="cd /app/my-project/ && yes | cp -rf /tmp/dist.tar.gz
```